# handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Tags: java, tls1.2, tomcat9, sslhandshakeexception

when i tried to enabled TLSv1.2 and cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for jms, i got the error which i mensioning with server.xml file below. i am using java 1.8.0_221, tomcat 9, spring2.9. then      i replaced the jar file of jce(java cryptography extension) in /security/policy/unlimited which downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html, but getting same error. i have executed following command to check jce policy > jrunscript -e "exit (println(javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") >= 256));"   the result is false

**>error**

> -------- Allow unsafe renegotiation: false Allow legacy hello messages: true Is initial handshake: true Is secure renegotiation:
> false Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported
> cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1 Ignoring
> unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported
> cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1 Ignoring
> unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for
> TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported
> cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1 Ignoring unsupported
> cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1 Ignoring
> unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for
> TLSv1.1 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1 Ignoring unsupported
> cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1 Ignoring
> unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for
> TLSv1.1 %% No cached client session update handshake state:
> client_hello[1](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html) upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
> *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1609878173 bytes = { 249, 22, 95, 249, 42, 246, 180, 241, 102, 79, 48, 131, 82, 55, 217, 46, 69,
> 118, 173, 155, 13, 170, 188, 28, 45, 107, 53, 45 } Session ID:  {}
> Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] Compression Methods:  { 0 }
> Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1,
> secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1,
> sect571r1, secp256k1} Extension ec_point_formats, formats:
> [uncompressed] Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms:
> SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA,
> SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA,
> SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA Extension extended_master_secret
> *** main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 193 main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 813 check handshake state: server_hello[2]
> *** ServerHello, TLSv1 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1609870596 bytes = { 82, 117, 120, 216, 104, 30, 226, 142, 149, 245, 48, 199, 220, 35, 55, 234,
> 192, 65, 5, 236, 34, 46, 7, 104, 196, 192, 207, 66 } Session ID:
> {211, 6, 0, 0, 74, 154, 90, 231, 222, 237, 76, 181, 155, 196, 93, 56,
> 200, 242, 251, 176, 8, 194, 23, 29, 168, 183, 148, 71, 154, 158, 61,
> 174} Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Compression
> Method: 0 Extension extended_master_secret Extension
> renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection:
>
> ---

**> server.xml**

```
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8082
    -->
    <!--<Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" /> -->
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    
    <!-- Define an SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<!-- Define an SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->

               
                   <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="700" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,+TLSv1.2"
keystoreFile="D:/Tomcat9/conf/key.jks" keystorePass="clientpass" keystoreType="JKS"
keyAlias="ibmwebspheremqshabeeb" ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"/>
               
<!--<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
           secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="D:/Tomcat9/conf/client.jks"
           keystorePass="clientpass"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           compression="force"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>-->


<!--<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="D:/Tomcat9/conf/client.jks" keystorePass="clientpass"
           clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>-->    
   
   <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    
  <!-- <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"/>
        <SSLHostConfig
             certificateKeystoreFile="D:/Tomcat9/conf/client.jks"
                         type="RSA" /> -->
        
   
    
    
    

 <!--<Connector className="org.apache.catalina.connector.http.HttpConnector"
           port="8443" minProcessors="5" maxProcessors="75"
           enableLookups="true"
           acceptCount="10" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true">
  <Factory className="org.apache.catalina.net.SSLServerSocketFactory"
           clientAuth="true" protocol="TLS"/>
</Connector>-->
 <!--<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocols="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" keystoreFile="D:/Tomcat9/conf/client.jks" keystorePass="clientpass"
           port="8443"/>-->
           
           


 <!--<Factory className="org.apache.catalina.net.SSLServerSocketFactory"
           clientAuth="true" protocol="TLS" 
       keystoreFile="C:/certificate/ibmclientm2.jks" keystorePass="clientpass"/>-->
       
     
    
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->

    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0):

> No available cipher suite for `TLSv1` jmsReplyQListener-1

You've to enable the support for TLSv1, so first update the connector tag in `server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
      maxThreads="700" scheme="https" secure="true"
         <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1,+TLSv1.2">
            <Certificate 
                 certificateKeystoreFile="D:/Tomcat9/conf/key.jks"
                 certificateKeystorePassword="clientpass"
                 type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Comment: Add support for TLSv1

Comment: yes, i have given the support for TLSv1 so i changed sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,+TLSv1.2" in server.xml file but getting error which i mensioned above , see error above , which is "Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1"  even though  i have given protocol TLSv1.2 in server.xml